# Parse *.txt file looping with comprehensive dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a *.txt file coming from a SQL query organised in rows.

I'm reading it with pandas library through:

```
df = pd.read_csv(./my_file_path/my_file.txt, sep = '\n', head = 0)
df.rename(columns = {list(df.columns)[0]: 'cols'}, inplace = True)
```

the output are rows with the information separated by spaces in an standard structure (dots are meant to be spaces):

```
  name................address........country..........age

0 Bob.Hope............Broadway.......United.States....101

1 Richard.Donner......Park.Avenue....United.States.....76

2 Oscar.Meyer.........Friedrichshain.Germany...........47
```

I tried to create a dictionary to get the info with comprehensive lists:

```
col_dict = {'name': [df.cols[i][0:20].strip() for i in range(0,len(df.cols))],
            'address': [df.cols[I][21:36].strip() for i in range(0,len(df.cols))], 
            'country': [df.cols[i][36:52].strip() for i in range(0,len(df.cols))],
            'age': [df.cols[i][53:].strip() for i in range(0,len(df.cols))],
            }
```

This script runs well in order to create a dictionary as a basis for a dataframe to work with.  But I were asking myself if there is any other way to make the script more pythonic, looping directly through a dictionary with the column names and avoiding the repetition of the same code for every column -the actual dataset is much longer-.
The question is how can I store de string indexation to use it later with the column names to parse everything at once.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. When you say `the output are rows...`, it's the output of what. It is also unclear as to what the problem is.

It seems that you may want the `sep` argument as `sep='\s+'` not `'\n'` which is a new line.

Comment: the structure of the dataframe are row with a single string once I read it with pandas -also in the txt file which has a fix number or characters per line, what I'd like is to know if there is a simple way to parse each column with a simplest script.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it directly with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(./my_file_path/my_file.txt, delim_whitespace=True)
```

If you know that the space between the columns is going to be at least 2 spaces, you can do it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(./my_file_path/my_file.txt, sep='\s{2,}')
```

In your case, the file is fixed width so you need to use a different method:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(my_text), widths=[20,15,16, 10],skiprows=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for this case because there are spaces in some fields I want to get (p.e. United States). Yields this error message: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 9, saw 19

Comment: @RodrigoVargas I updated the code with something to handle the United States case. It works if you know that there will be at least 2 spaces between each column.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work either. You're right, the point is the some columns are separated by a single space.

Answer (score 1):

The [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) method is what you are looking for.

```py
df = pd.read_fwf( 'data.txt' )
```

`data.txt`

```
name                address        country          age

Bob Hope            Broadway       United States    101

Richard Donner      Park Avenue    United States     76

Oscar Meyer         Friedrichshain Germany           47
```

`df`

| id | name | address | country | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bob Hope | Broadway | United States | 101 |
| 1 | Richard Donner | Park Avenue | United States | 76 |
| 2 | Oscar Meyer | Friedrichshain | Germany | 47 |

Comment: That's a good point. This method parse the dataframe, but still has problems with some columns that it parse together. Mainly those with only a single space between them.

Comment: @RodrigoVargas This method will actually work for your case as you will  specify the width of each column.

Comment: @RodrigoVargas I suggest trying it, I verified that it works witht he data you provided.

Comment: Sorry @bicarlsen I’ve tried but there must be something that I’m doing wrong. When I pass the width list it doesn’t parse in the correct format

Comment: Try without the width list so it infers. If you need more help then I suggest making your actual data available so I can test it.